# Query chain data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

I have a table sample below:
Table_A

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 881 | 113 |
| 988 | 899 |
| 113 | 765 |
| 765 | 765 |
| 122 | 881 |
| 300 | 400 |
| 765 | 910 |
| 910 | 345 |
| 999 | 988 |

What I want to achieve here, is to get the last chaining data based on table above with the requirement as the following, each data must find their chain data based on col2 to col1 until the data not find any chain and ignore the data with the same value for example in this case for the col1 = 122 and col2 = 881 should be 122>881>113>765>910>365. For the data that does not have any data chain or data with the same value could be leave it in blank or null.

I try to do self-join, but it only accommodates 1 time chain only. I am looking for dynamic chain based on the number of data itself.

```
SELECT A.col1,
       A.col2,
       B.col1
FROM Table_A AS A
LEFT JOIN Table_A AS B
```

The expecting result as follow:

| col1 | col2 | last_chain_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 881 | 113 | 345 |
| 988 | 899 | NULL |
| 113 | 765 | 345 |
| 765 | 765 | NULL |
| 122 | 881 | 345 |
| 300 | 400 | NULL |
| 765 | 910 | 345 |
| 910 | 345 | NULL |
| 999 | 988 | 899 |

is there any method to achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: can there be more than one record with the same col1 (ignoring the record with col1=col2)?  if so, there can be multiple last chain values

Comment: @ysth for the time being I just aware and focused on this example but I am write down that and keep it as possible issue in the future, let's just say yes it could be more than one record.

Comment: The scheme does not forbid cycles. Unsolvable in current state. Imagine there are 3 rows, (1,2), (2,3), (3,1) - what output for any of these rows do you want to receive?

Comment: If there are no cycles, you should be able to do this with a recursive CTE.

Comment: It will be more reliable to process cycles with unique Id column. At least through row_number().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS (
  SELECT col1, col2, CAST(col2 AS CHAR(65535)) path, 1 level
  FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte1.col1, cte1.col2, CONCAT_WS(',', cte1.path, test.col2), cte1.level + 1
  FROM test
  JOIN cte1 ON FIND_IN_SET(test.col1, cte1.path)
  WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(test.col2, cte1.path)
  ),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY LENGTH(path) DESC) rn
  FROM cte1
  )
SELECT col1, col2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, ',', -1) last_chain_data
FROM cte2 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY last_chain_data, level DESC;
```

| col1 | col2 | last_chain_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | 881 | 345 |
| 881 | 113 | 345 |
| 113 | 765 | 345 |
| 765 | 765 | 345 |
| 765 | 910 | 345 |
| 910 | 345 | 345 |
| 300 | 400 | 400 |
| 999 | 988 | 899 |
| 988 | 899 | 899 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kFDuRwVJ)

Comment: doesn't match the requested output, which has null where there is no second record in the chain

Comment: @ysth This can be easily fixed by counting the commas amount in `path`.

Comment: with the way you can join onto an earlier-starting chain, it's not clear to me that it is easily fixed.

Comment: @Akina this is the close one that I am looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: @Akina is there anyway to change find_in_set to where in? Because as we know find_in_set are not using index. I tested in with a lot of data in become slow, any thoughts?

Comment: @MuhtaromZain *is there anyway to change find_in_set to where in?* There is no ARRAY datatype in MySQL. You may use JSON array and MEMBER OF, but I doubt that this will be more fast.

Answer (score 0):

Another recursive query example

```
with RECURSIVE trn as(select *,row_number()over(order by col1,col2) rn from test)
, r as(
  select 0 lvl,t1.rn,t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col2 next, t2.rn next_rn
    ,concat(':',t1.rn,':',t2.rn) path
  from trn t1 left join trn t2
     on t2.col1=t1.col2 and t1.rn<>t2.rn
  union all
  select lvl+1 lvl,r.rn,r.col1,r.col2,t.col2 next,t.rn 
    ,concat(path,':',t.rn) path
  from r left  join trn t
     on t.col1=r.next and t.rn<>r.rn
  where lvl<7 and locate(t.rn,path)=0
)
select *
  from(
  select * 
     ,row_number()over(partition by rn order by lvl desc)rrn
  from r
  ) x
where rrn=1;
```

Output is

| lvl | rn | col1 | col2 | next | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 113 | 765 | 345 | :1:4:5:7 |
| 4 | 2 | 122 | 881 | 345 | :2:6:1:4:5:7 |
| 0 | 3 | 300 | 400 | null | null |
| 1 | 4 | 765 | 765 | 345 | :4:5:7 |
| 0 | 5 | 765 | 910 | 345 | :5:7 |
| 3 | 6 | 881 | 113 | 345 | :6:1:4:5:7 |
| 0 | 7 | 910 | 345 | null | null |
| 0 | 8 | 988 | 899 | null | null |
| 0 | 9 | 999 | 988 | 899 | :9:8 |

About (765, 765)-->null  - why the result should be like this should be further described in the question.  I don't want to guess.  In this case, the result may be ambiguous.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Co2ih3XE)

Answer (score 0):

The table could really benefit from an `id` column. But it's still possbile without it:

```
create table Table_A (col1 int, col2 int);
insert Table_A values
(881,113),
(988,899),
(113,765),
(765,765),
(122,881),
(300,400),
(765,910),
(910,345),
(999,988);
```

Here is the query:

```
with recursive
i as    (select row_number() over() as id,col1,col2
        from table_a), -- as we don't have an id column, we add one here. The table i will be used later on instead of the orginal table
c as    (
        select t1.id, t1.col1,t1.col2
        from i t1 
        left join i t2
        on t1.col2=t2.col1
        where t1.col1<>t1.col2 and t2.col1 is not null
        union 
        select c.id, t.col1,t.col2
        from i t
        right join c
        on c.col2=t.col1
        where t.col1 is not null and t.col1<>t.col2 -- if t.col1<>t.col2 is removed here, the recursive process will have meaningless calculation when t.col1<>t.col2    
) -- table c is to calculate for those rows which have a chained row, also the rows whose col1<>col2
select col1,col2,last_chain_data -- this outter layer is used to make sure each row appears in their original order from the base table, as UNION statement doesn't enforce the feature of ORDER BY clause within it) 
from (select distinct id,first_value(col1)  over w as col1,first_value(col2)  over w as col2,last_value(col2) over w as last_chain_data
     from c  window w as (partition by id) -- the first query in the UNION is to get the required output for those rows which have a chained row, also the rows whose col1<>col2
     UNION
     select distinct t1.id,t1.col1,t1.col2,null
     from i t1 
     left join i t2
     on t1.col2=t2.col1  
     where t1.col1=t1.col2 or t2.col1 is null  -- contrary to the 1st query, the second query in the UNION is for those rows which don't have a chained row, also the rows whose col1=col2
) tb
order by id
;

-- result
+------+------+-----------------+
| col1 | col2 | last_chain_data |
+------+------+-----------------+
|  881 |  113 |             345 |
|  988 |  899 |            NULL |
|  113 |  765 |             345 |
|  765 |  765 |            NULL |
|  122 |  881 |             345 |
|  300 |  400 |            NULL |
|  765 |  910 |             345 |
|  910 |  345 |            NULL |
|  999 |  988 |             899 |
+------+------+-----------------+
```

See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o1sJwMD7DFRg7iQc2wnJsU/1